# Login system using Passport.js is always executing “failureRedirect” (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, passport.js, body-parser

I'm doing a tutorial and I'm stuck in the login area. When I'm login in with Passport.js it always executing "failureRedirect" in authenticate.

After trying to debug replacing the router.post('login') route I received the following message:

> Error: null User: false Info: {"message":"Missing credentials"}

After Reading on some forums I think that the problem could be related to body-parser. I've been trying to solve the problem but I haven't been able yet. I'd appreciate the help of a most experienced node.js programmer.

The structure of the project is:
app.js
  routes:
    users.js
  models:
    user.js

**user.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var User = require('../models/user');

var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });

// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register', {
    title: 'Register'
  });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', {
    'title': 'Login'
  });
});

router.post('/register', upload.single('profileimage'), function (req, res, next) {
  //Get Form Values
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var password2 = req.body.password2;


  // Check for Image Field
  if(req.files && req.files.profileimage){
    console.log('Uploading File...');

    // File Info
    var profileImageOriginalName = req.files.profileimage.originalname;
    var profileImageName = req.files.profileimage.name;
    var profileImageMime = req.files.profileimage.mimetype;
    var profileImagePath = req.files.profileimage.path;
    var profileImageExt = req.files.profileimage.extension;
    var profileImageSize = req.files.profileimage.size;
  } else {
    // Set a Default Image
    var profileImageName = 'noimage.png';
  }

  // Form Validation
  req.checkBody('name', 'Name field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email not valid').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('username', 'Username field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

  // Check for errors
  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if(errors){
    res.render('register', {
      errors: errors,
      name: name,
      email: email,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      password2: password2
    });
  } else {
    var newUser = new User({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      profileImage: profileImageName
    });

    // Create User
    User.createUser(newUser, function (err, user) {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(user);
    });

    //Success Message
    req.flash('success', 'You are now registered and may log in');

    res.location('/');
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function (username, password, done) {
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function (err, user) {
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        console.log('Unknown User');
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
      }

      User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          console.log('Invalid Password');
          return done(null, false, {message:'Invalid Password'});
        }
      });
    });
  }
));

router.post('/login', jsonParser, passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/users/login',
  failureFlash: true //'Invalid username or password'
}), function (req, res) {
  console.log('Authentication Successful');
  req.flash('success', 'You are logged in');
  res.redirect('/');
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
  console.log("authenticate");
  console.log(err);
  console.log(user);
  console.log(info);
}), function (req, res) {
  console.log('Authentication Successful');
  req.flash('success', 'You are logged in');
  res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**user.js**

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodeauth');

var db = mongoose.connection;

// User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    bcrypt: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  name:{
    type: String
  },
  profileimage:{
    type: String
  }

});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassowrd, hash, callback) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassowrd, hash, function (err, isMatch) {
    if(err) return callback(err);
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
}

module.exports.getUserById = function (id, callback) {
  User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function (username, callback) {
  var query = {username: username};
  User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.createUser = function (newUser, callback) {
  bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
    if(err) throw err;

    // Set hashed pw
    newUser.password = hash;

    // Create User
    newUser.save(callback);
  });
}
```

**app.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// Handle File Uploads
// app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads'}));
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Handle Express Sessions
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));

// Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
    var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));
// app.use(expressValidator({
//   errorFormatter
// }));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Files on Dropbox:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ex26xxo85lfo0my/AADET-j6Ift0q-y-ecWCRUEba?dl=0

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: CODE THAT I USED TO DEBUG ON THE ROUTE users.js

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
  console.log("authenticate");
  console.log(err);
  console.log(user);
  console.log(info);
}), function (req, res) {
  console.log('Authentication Successful');
  req.flash('success', 'You are logged in');
  res.redirect('/');
});

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code here on https://github.com/rupalipemare/Mongoose-Demo, wherein there is complete example demonstrating passport authentication.

Comment: Thanks Rupali, that's very kind from you :)

Comment: Hope the example helped you !

Answer (score 0):

First.. Please try to modularize code. Putting a functionalities in different files can help you track bugs faster. Second why are there two POST calls to login route? Remove the first one and no need to send jsonParser. Yo have declared to serialize and deserialize user. So passport will handle rest.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, the code is modularized. Here you have a link to the code for you to have a closer look.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ex26xxo85lfo0my/AADET-j6Ift0q-y-ecWCRUEba?dl=0
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the second one should be commented. I was trying to debug showing the details on the console